# What's the name for a table that does not hold "mutable" data?

Tags: terminology

Let's say I have a `users` table, and each user has a different level of privilege. I have a `privileges` table with four rows that looks like this:

```
id | level
---+-----------
1  | viewer
2  | editor
3  | admin
4  | super-admin
```

In the business context, my *users* all have a *privilege level*, 1-4. The `users` table holds the corresponding user data, and it gets modified when users are modified, added, or dropped, but `privileges` never really changes, it is just a reference of the four established *privilege levels*.

Is there a name or term for this type of table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be called an enum, a reference table or a meta-data table.

I prefer to call that kind of table by its real name, i.e. in your case "privileges" or perhaps "PrivilegeLevels".  I don't tend to make distinctions between tables where rows change, and tables where rows don't often change since that tends to needlessly add nomenclature for its own sake.